# C# low level keyboard device

Tags: c#, keyboard, device

I am writing a C# dll for barcode scanner that emulates keyboard. I am fighting with this for some time. I have problems with raw input. All examples that i found require MainApplication window handle. How to attach to device and get scanned barcode without it. Second problem is that i have to know from which keyboard it was sent from.

I tried to get it using this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

It gets me data and device name but require window handle.

Do you have any ideas?

m.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have code to initialize the setup, and when a barcode is scanned from a device, log the device name and assign that to the keyboard either in a config file or database.

Then you know.

Comment: I think you did not understand me or i did not you. I need from console application hok to keyboard device and listen to data input and at the same time check from which device it is comming. If it is from barcode (I know this device handle) proceed it if not leave it.

Comment: For me problem is in this part of code:

IntPtr p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource source = System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.FromHwnd(p);
source.AddHook(new System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceHook(WndProc)); 

MainWindowHandle is somethig that i do not have. And I cannot attach to windows messages. Answer to that will work for me